# pandas remove rows when consecutive row values of particular columns are more than a number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
col1    col2 
  A      1
  B      2
  C      3
  D      3
  E      3
  F      4
  G      5
  H      5
  I      5
  J      5
```

Now I want to delete those rows where consecutive col2 values are more than 3 times, in above data frame the col2 values of 5 occurred more than 3 times so those rows should be deleted. so the final data frame should look like,

```
col1    col2 
 A      1
 B      2
 C      3
 D      3
 E      3
 F      4
```

I could do this using a for loop with a counter check in, but the execution time will be more. Looking for some pythonic way/pandas shortcut to do it efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for count values and then filter by [`Series.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html) for less or equal in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['col2'].map(df['col2'].value_counts()).le(3)]
print (df)
  col1  col2
0    A     1
1    B     2
2    C     3
3    D     3
4    E     3
5    F     4
```

For test consecutive values is used helper `Series` with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and pass to [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) (and specify column after it):

```
g = df['col2'].ne(df['col2'].shift()).cumsum()
df = df[df.groupby([g,'col2'])['col2'].transform('size').le(3)]
print (df)
  col1  col2
0    A     1
1    B     2
2    C     3
3    D     3
4    E     3
5    F     4
```

Comment: I think it should be for consecutive values

Answer (score 1):

To identify **consecutive** values, usually you need `cumsum` on differences and groupby:

```
groups = df.col2.ne(df.col2.shift()).cumsum()

group_sizes = df.groupby(groups).transform('size')

out = df[group_sizes <= 3)
```